# How can I make a flag for query, so that if the records are added it says "successful", if not then says "unsuccessful"

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

I have made a database with Java SWING application. It is performing the four queries of INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE and SAVE. When the records are added successfully it shows the dialogue box of successful. But how can I make a flag here that shows the message of "*successful*" when records are entered, and of "*unsuccessful*" when the records are not entered due to any reason.

Here is the code of the insert query:

```
  String sql = "insert into customer (cust_id, cust_name, father_name, birth_date, CNIC, city, card_num, acc_num, bank_name, address, email, ph_num) values  ( " + String.valueOf(txtcust_id.getText()) + ",'" + txtcust_name.getText() + "','" + txtf_name.getText() + "','" + txtb_date.getText() + "' , '" + txtcnic.getText() + "','" + txtcity.getText() + "','" + txtcard_num.getText() + "','" + txtacc_num.getText() + "','" + txtb_n.getText() + "','" + txtadd.getText() + "','" + txtemail.getText() + "','" + txtph_num.getText() + "' )";
  stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Insert Query Executed Successfully"
                ,"Execution Alert", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: You need to show us your code.

Comment: The return value of `Statement.executeUpdate()` tells you how many rows were inserted.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the number of rows affected by the given query:

```
int rows = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
String msg = "Insert Query Execution Failed";
if(0 < rows) {
  msg = "Insert Query Executed Successfully";
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, msg, "Execution Alert", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

**P.S.** Do use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) in-case of runtime parameters

**EDIT**:

Your given exception `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near ','` clearly states that the insert query is not properly formed, possibly your passing special characters from those text fields e.g. `,` or `'`.

Query would look like this:

```
String sql = "insert into customer (cust_id, cust_name, father_name, birth_date, CNIC, city, card_num, acc_num, bank_name, address, email, ph_num) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(txtcust_id.getText()));
stmt.setString(2, txtcust_name.getText());
...
stmt.setDate(4, sqlDateDOB);
```

**String to sql date**

```
String str = txtb_date.getText();//must not be empty text !
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy,MM,dd");
java.sql.Date sqlDateDOB = new java.sql.Date(fmt.parse(str).getTime());
```

Sample [date conversion done here](https://ideone.com/uzUG4z)

Comment: it's giving me the error of incorrect syntax near ',' and i can't seem to find it. can you help?

Comment: SEVERE: null
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: and i have no idea how to use prepared statements

Comment: ok so if i want to make a prepared statement of the above query i posted. Should i just write coloumn name = ? like cust_id = ? and replace ? with getter()? also how will it take the date and int data in prepared statement?

Comment: can you do me a huge favor and make me a prepared statement for the query i posted? because i am unable to understand them at the moment? thank you

Comment: ok now what i have to do here is do it like this... for cust_id i will use.. SetInt(1, txtcust_id.gettext()) ?

Comment: and one more question please.. same thing for date and email? because i tried all this last night.. only problem i was having was with date. and BIGINT

Comment: and after all this i can run stmt.executeUpdate()? and put in your validation cod?

Comment: @Spring Learner.. just need to know if i should use setLong for BIGINT data type in SQL? and what to do about DATE.

Comment: it is yyyy,mm,dd.. this is my code i am getting stmt.setDate(4, txtb_date.getText()); and i am getting error that String cannot be converted into DATE

Comment: @SamarQureshi yes setLong for bigint values

Comment: now its giving this error java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""